# How to respond to the Taimanov attack in the Benoni?

Tags: opening, modern-benoni

```
 [FEN ""]
  1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 c5 3.d5 e6 4.Nc3 exd5 5.cxd5 d6 6.e4 g6 7.f4 Bg7 8.Bb5+
```

How can black respond in the following position?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1015108) helps you. Your choices are: `8. ... Nbd7`, `8. ... Nfd7` and `8. ... Bd7`.

Answer (score 6):

**8...Nfd7** is the most popular line among Grandmasters.

[Bareev vs Topalov 2002, 0-1](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1252423)

[Bostari vs Polgar 2011 0-1](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1693668)

**8...Nbd7** is extremely risky and requires thorough preparation. White does seem to get at least a minimal endgame advantage in the 8...Nbd7 line with best play by Black. Since the advent of strong engines, Grandmasters have avoided it and I would recommend avoiding it as well.

**8...Bd7** is just bad and White easily gets an advantage.

I provide some sample lines -

```
     [Event "8...Nfd7 is Black's best move"]
     [Date "2014.10.26"]          
     [FEN ""]

     1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 c5 4. d5 exd5 5. cxd5 d6 6. e4 g6 7. f4 Bg7 8. Bb5+
     Nfd7 (8... Nbd7 9. e5 dxe5 10. fxe5 Nh5 11. e6 Qh4+ 12. g3! (12. Kd2?! fxe6 13.
     dxe6 O-O 14. exd7 Bxd7 15. Bxd7 Rf2+ 16. Nge2 Rd8=) 12... Nxg3 13. hxg3 Qxh1 14.
     Be3 Bxc3+ (14... O-O 15. exd7 Bxd7 16. Bxd7 Rfe8 17. Bxe8 Rxe8 18. Qe2 Bh6 19.
     Kf1 Bxe3 20. Qg2) (14... Qg2 15. exd7+ Bxd7 16. Bxd7+ Kxd7 17. Qg4+ Kd8 18.
     O-O-O) 15. bxc3 a6 16. exd7+ Bxd7 17. Bxd7+ Kxd7 18. Qg4+ f5 19. Qf3 Qxf3 20.
     Nxf3) (8... Bd7? 9. e5 dxe5 (9... Qe7 10. Qe2 dxe5 (10... Nh5 11. g4) 11. d6)
     10. fxe5 Nh5 11. Nf3 O-O 12. Bxd7 Nxd7 13. g4) 9. a4 O-O (9... Qh4+!? 10. g3 Qe7
     11. Nf3 O-O 12. O-O Na6 13. Re1 Nb4) 10. Nf3 Na6 11. O-O Nb4 12. Re1 a6 13. Bf1
     Re8
```

Answer (score 0):

...Nbd7 is not a good continuation since there is too much theory relating to this line. Besides, it is better for White. The safe line is ...Nfd7, which opens up the diagonal for the Bg7. A common mistake here is White not playing a2-a4, because if not, Black can get his queenside majority into action with ...a6 and ...b5.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to not play c5 until white commits to Nf3. There are dozens of ways to transpose into these lines. As an example, you play 1.d4, Nf6 2. c4, e6 and now if white plays 3. Nc3 you go into a Nimzo but if 3. Nf3 you can play the Benoni and avoid the Taimanov.

The alternative is to spend a few weeks analyzing the Taimanov in depth and come up with a really good novelty.

Comment: The Taimanov is not as dangerous as previously thought. 8...Nfd7 9. 0-0, and black has at least 2 major options. More potent today are the h3 systems.

Comment: Even if the current theory says it's fine, its still not a fun line to play as black.